# Geoserver ImageMosaic index is not updating with cURL

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic, geoserver-rest-api, curl

I am successfully adding a new ImageMosaic of GeoTiffs with the Geoserver REST API

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d "file://D:/tifdirectory" "http://localhost:8088/geoserver/rest/workspaces/wsp/coveragestores/tifdirectory/external.imagemosaic"
```

The .SHP index is then created in my "tifdirectory" along with the "tifdirectory.properties" file and everything works well after I setup the layer parameters directly in Geoserver.

My GeoTIFFs are updated daily, so I need to update the footprint index. I tried with this command:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d "file://D:/tifdirectory" "http://localhost:8088/geoserver/rest/workspaces/wsp/coveragestores/tifdirectory/external.imagemosaic"
```

At first, it seems to work since there is no error in the response, I receive:

```
* upload completely sent off: 72 out of 72 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
```

But my ImageMosaic index (.SHP) is not updated. What am I missing here? Is there another way to update to mosaic index?

---

I think that I could make it work by deleting the layer and coveragestore daily before creating it back. But, when I create the layer I need to manually edit the parameters in Geoserver UI. How can I create it with cURL with all the parameters (crs, BackgroundValues, SUGGESTED_TILE_SIZE, etc) already set?

Comment: have you tried the recalculate parameter? http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/api/coveragestores.html#recalculate

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen before and don't understand why (never debugged the source all the way through GeoServer & GeoTools).

Try specifically adding each new image instead of just giving it the directory.  That was a viable workaround for the issue the last time I saw this happen on my home PC.

> ```
> curl -v -u username:password -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/plain" \
>  -d "file://D:/tifdirectory/YOUR_IMAGE.tif" \
>  "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/YOUR_WORKSPACE/coveragestores/YOUR_STORE/external.imagemosaic"
> ```