# Updating existing GeoServer ImageMosaic with GeoTIFF using REST API

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, image-mosaic, geoserver-rest-api

While trying to update an existing ImageMosaic in GeoServer using the REST API, following the documentation (provided here http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html#uploading-and-modifying-a-image-mosaic)

using the following command

`curl -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d "file:///path/to/file/img.tiff" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/opengeo/coveragestores/klicfinal/external.imagemosaic"`

I get an empty response, while my ImageMosaic remains un-updated. Does anyone have a clue as to what could be causing this?

EDIT: I've already tried using the recalculate parameter. Furthermore, after closer examination, the shapefile of the imagemosaic has been updated and already shows the location and the reference to the new geotiff file. However, the newly added image does not show up in the WMS layer preview, even after disabling caching.

Even the GML that you can get using `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/opengeo/coveragestores/klicfinal/coverages/klicfinal/index/granules.xml?`
shows the updated reference to the newly uploaded GeoTIFF.

```
Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
POST /geoserver/rest/workspaces/opengeo/coveragestores/klicfinal/external.imagemosaic HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: */*
Content-type: text/plain
Content-Length: 83

upload completely sent off: 83 out of 83 bytes
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Date: Tue, 11 Apr 2017 14:33:17 GMT
Server Noelios-Restlet-Engine/1.0..8 is not blacklisted
Server: Noelios-Restlet-Engine/1.0..8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: what does the log file say happened? try turning up the logging level if you can't find anything useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207460/geoserver-imagemosaic-index-is-not-updating-with-curl?rq=1

Comment: I've already tried the recalculate parameter in the question that you linked to. Will try to look at the log file next. Furthermore, the shapefile of that imagemosaic has been updated and already shows the location and the reference to the new geotiff file. However, they do not show up in the WMS, even after disabling caching.

Comment: please edit the question to add this new information - so it basically works but doesn't show up

Comment: you say it updates your .shp but does it update the .dbf with your image name?  you can  view the .dbf as text.  also, what version of GeoServer?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-5833 however you don't specify which version of GeoServer you're running, so impossible to be sure (has been fixed since 2.11.3 and 2.12.0).