# Update imagemosaic store in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, image-mosaic

I have crated an imagemosaic store in GeoServer with a default TIFF image named **snow_20091001.tif** it is working fine. I can see the layer from layer preview.

But the problem is, as it is a timeseries layer, I have added another image **snow_20091101.tif** manually to the store. This image is not showing when I am requesting with the time. But the previously added image is showing fine.

I have not configured PostGIS database as **datastore.properties** as I want to use shapefile index by default.

should I update the store to get the later on added image?
If so then how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [guide](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/imagemosaic.html#updating-an-image-mosaic-contents):

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d "file:///path/to/the/file/polyphemus_20130302.nc"
   "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/topp/coveragestores/poly-incremental/external.imagemosaic"
```

This might not work however per [Updating existing GeoServer ImageMosaic with GeoTIFF using REST API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236573/updating-existing-geoserver-imagemosaic-with-geotiff-using-rest-api)