# Adding granules to GeoServer store doesn't update time dimension of WMS?

Tags: qgis, raster, geoserver, time-series, image-mosaic

I'm pretty new to using GeoServer, so I'm sorry if this question has been asked already and I just was unable to use the correct verbage to find it. I've been following [this](https://www.earder.com/tutorials/timeseries-with-geoserver-and-openlayers/) tutorial to add a raster time-series to GeoServer using the ImageMosaic plug-in. I've gotten it to work with the data they provided.

In this tutorial I set up a store using a directory named `timeseries` in the `coverages` directory of the GeoServer. For my needs, I will need to constantly update this directory by adding a new daily raster.

For example, the tutorial had me add three files, `timeseries_20030517.tif`, `timeseries_20130201.tif`, and `timeseries_20170803.tif`.

To mimic my need of this feature I copied the first file and renamed it `timeseries_20170804.tif`. However the changes are not reflected when I view the WMS in QGIS. Only the data for 20170803 appears.

I've even tried removing the sample data from the tutorial entirely and inputting my own data with the same `timeseries_yyyyMMdd` format, but adding additional dates. The actual data clearly changes. However, when I look at the getcapabilities.xml of the WMS the time extent still shows:

```
<Extent name="time" default="2003-05-17T00:00:00Z">2003-05-17T00:00:00.000Z,2013-02-01T00:00:00.000Z,2017-08-03T00:00:00.000Z</Extent>
```

Is this a restriction of the ImageMosaic capabilities or is there something happening that I'm not doing correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236573/updating-existing-geoserver-imagemosaic-with-geotiff-using-rest-api

Comment: the solution is not helpful as i'm on version 2.19

Comment: the answer is the same as before - use the recalculate parmeter